# Is there a quick way to find "zero audio" regions in an audio mix ?

Tags: mixing, television, daw, tips

Sometimes, when I work as a re-recording mixer for TV, my mix can have a small region (can be 1 frame), that has no sound at all.
My colleagues, who make the final master for future broadcasting, then see this "hole" with their analyzing station with exact Timecode. "Zero data" isn't accepted by the TV broadcaster.

Is there a quick way to detect this myself ?

I work on Pyramix at work (really good DAW), but have my laptop with Pro Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pro tools there's the Strip Silence feature (Command U). You can set the Strip Threshold to -96db and all others (Min Strip Duration, Clip Start/End Pad) to 0msec. This should help you locate the holes. Not sure if pyramix has a similar feature.

Answer (score 1):

In pro tools you can do a strip silence. Or that might not be it? First thing i thought of